# What change happened for Timestamp in HyperSql 2.3 compared to HyperSql 2.0?

Tags: hibernate, timestamp, hsqldb

We use HyperSql as our unit test database, we have a hql (we use hibernate 3.3.1) like this

```
select count(*) from TestTable where create_date <= current_timestamp;
```

the type of create_date is timestamp. The code works fine for HyperSql 2.0, but not for HyperSql 2.3.

Is anybody know what changed for timestamp implementation from 2.0 to 2.3? Is it any change related to Timezone? I checked the HyperSql Changenotes but found nothing.

**Update**
Here is the details:
HyperSql used as in memory DB for unit testing. The schema is generated based on annotated class automatically. The create_date column is mapped like below:

```
@Column(name = "create_date", nullable = false)
    public Timestamp getCreateDate() {
    return createDate;
}
```

The testing is,1) empty the database, 2) call one method that should insert a record in the database 3) check db contains a record that has a record with create_date<=current_timestamp.

If got the field only with hibernate , the output like this

```
createDate=2015-01-06 13:06:42.132
current_timestamps=2015-01-06 13:06:42.4
```

it works fine with HyperSQL 2.0, but with 2.3, zero records returned. I guess it is the timezone issue, but from the printed output, I didn't see timezone information. The time displayed was local time. My host's timezone is CST (UTC+8).

Any suggestion on how to debug it?

Comment: What exactly does "not work"? Please show some sample data (`create table ...`, `insert into ...`, `select ...`) that reproduces your problem

Comment: Updated with detailed information. I think it relates to Timezone, but I am wondering how to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell. Hibernate 3.3.1 is too old and not fully compatible with HSQLDB 2.x.

It can also be a time zone issue. The TIMESTAMP type is by default without a time zone but CURRENT_TIMESTAMP has an implicit time zone. LOCALTIMESTAMP has no time zone and should be used in comparison with a plain TIMESTAMP column.

Update: This has been checked and found to be a regression when one timestamp is with and the other without time zone. It has been fixed and committed to SVN for the next version 2.3.3.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try